# Is measure of $\bar{E}$ always equal to zero, where $E$ has measure $0$ and nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

let E is subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ,where E is nowhere dense and outer measure of $E=0$. Then outer measure of $\bar{E}=0$?
I think is there exist a subset of
$\mathbb{R}$ that is nowhere dense set and has measure zero whose closure is equal to generalised Cantor set having some positive measure.
Any Hint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $C$ be a fat Cantor set (i.e.  Cantor set of positive measure). Let $E$ be  a countbale dense  set in $C$. Then $E$ is nowhere dense because its closure $C$ has no interior. $E$ has measure $0$ but its closure has positive measure.

Comment: Can we take intersection of all rational number between $[0,1]$ with fat Cantor set having some positive measure as a countable dense set?

Comment: @Tony that depends on the construction of $C$, which may have no rational elements - see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133236/6460

Comment: No you cannot do that. But every subset of $\mathbb R$ (and every subset of any separable metric space) is separable. There is alwasy a countable dense  set in any subset of $\mathbb R$. @Tony

Comment: @Tony ... "Can we take intersection of all rational number between [0,1]
with fat Cantor set"  That depends on the fact Cantor set $C$.  If you construct $C$ so that the endpoints of the intervals removed are all rational, then yes.

Comment: Thankyou for your help..